# What is the meaning of multiple kernels in keras lstm layer?

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm

On https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/ I see that LSTM layers have a `kernel` and a `recurrent_kernel`. What is their meaning? In my understanding, we need weights for the 4 gates of an LSTM cell. However, in keras implementation, `kernel` has a shape of (input_dim, 4*units) and `recurrent_kernel` has a shape of (units, 4*units). So, are both of them somehow implementing the gates?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you take a look at the LSTM equations:

[image]

You have 4 **W** matrices that transform the input and 4 **U** matrices that transform the hidden state.

Keras saves these sets of 4 matrices into the `kernel` and `recurrent_kernel` weight arrays. From [the code that uses them](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1d81a20292ca6926e595d06a6cd725dbb104a146/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1911):

```
self.kernel_i = self.kernel[:, :self.units]
self.kernel_f = self.kernel[:, self.units: self.units * 2]
self.kernel_c = self.kernel[:, self.units * 2: self.units * 3]
self.kernel_o = self.kernel[:, self.units * 3:]

self.recurrent_kernel_i = self.recurrent_kernel[:, :self.units]
self.recurrent_kernel_f = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units: self.units * 2]
self.recurrent_kernel_c = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 2: self.units * 3]
self.recurrent_kernel_o = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 3:]
```

Apparently the 4 matrices are stored inside the weight arrays concatenated along the second dimension, which explains the weight array shapes.

Comment: hmm, interesting. There seem to be two different versions of LSTMs out there. I was referring to http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/
They are concatenating input and hidden state and thus only have 4 weight matrices

Comment: I guess Keras wants to allow you to specify separate regularizers and constraints for the two matrices. Then splitting the weights into separate matrices makes sense.