# Kernel and Recurrent Kernel in Keras LSTMs

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to draw in my mind the structure of the LSTMs and I don't understand what are the Kernel and Recurrent Kernel. According to this [post](https://mc.ai/a-practical-guide-to-rnn-and-lstm-in-keras/) in LSTMs section, the Kernel it's the four matrices that are multiplied by the inputs and Recurrent Kernel it's the four matrices that are multiplied by the hidden state, but, what are those 4 matrices in this diagram?

[image]

Are the gates?

I was testing with this [app](https://netron.app/) how the `unit` variable of the code below affect the kernel, recurrent kernel and bias:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(unit = 1, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
```

with `look_back = 1` it returns me that:

[image]

with `unit = 2` it returns me this

[image]

With `unit = 3` this

[image]

Testing with this values I could deducted this expressions

[image]

but I don't know how this works by inside. What does mean `<1x(4u)>` or `<ux(4u)>`? `u = units`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernels are basically the weights handled by the LSTM cell

units = neurons, like the classic multilayer perceptron

It is not shown in your diagram, but the input is a vector X with 1 or more values, and each value is sent in a neuron with its own weight w (the which we are going to learn with backpropagation)

The four matrices are these (expressed as Wf, Wi, Wc, Wo):

[image: The weights]

When you add a neuron, you are adding other 4 weights\kernel

So for your input vector X you have four matrix. And therefore

```
1 * 4 * units = kernel
```

Regarding the `recurrent_kernel` [here you can find the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723284/what-is-the-meaning-of-multiple-kernels-in-keras-lstm-layer).
Basically in keras input and hidden state are not concatenated like in the example diagrams (*W[ht-1, t]*) but they are split and handled with other four matrices called *U*:

[image: how keras handle input x and hidden state ht-1]

Because you have a hidden state x neuron, the weights U (all four U) are:

```
units * (4 * units) = recurrent kernel
```

ht-1 comes in a recurrent way from all your neurons. Like in a multilayer perceptron, each output of a neuron goes in all the next recurrent layer neurons

source: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Comment: In the `1 * (4*units) = kernel` and `units * (4*units) = recurrent kernel`, what's the meaning of `1` and `units` (at the beginning of the two equations), and why are they different?